I am loading 100 data into the recycler view at once and then the application crashes with the mentioned error
ANR in in.app.balaji
    PID: 9948
    Reason: App requested: MainThread worked timeout
    ErrorId: 8e317451-e531-43d9-b310-42b887bfd4c2
    Frozen: false
    Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=3.88 avg60=1.98 avg300=1.26 total=3095676089
    full avg10=1.37 avg60=0.64 avg300=0.38 total=996839902
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/cpu -----
    some avg10=12.41 avg60=6.46 avg300=4.55 total=20593166863
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/cpu -----
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/io -----
    some avg10=3.20 avg60=1.35 avg300=0.78 total=3793799535
    full avg10=1.29 avg60=0.43 avg300=0.24 total=1815292022
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/io -----

    CPU usage from 175018ms to -1ms ago (2024-01-25 15:46:00.073 to 2024-01-25 15:48:55.093):
      16% 1969/system_server: 8.7% user + 7.5% kernel / faults: 69086 minor 114 major
      13% 1562/surfaceflinger: 9% user + 4.7% kernel / faults: 3715 minor 65 major
      5.5% 879/adbd: 1% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 10979 minor 2 major
      4.4% 6113/com.google.android.providers.media.module: 1.7% user + 2.7% kernel / faults: 8613 minor 126 major
      4% 4221/com.android.systemui: 2.7% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 35944 minor 210 major
      3.6% 1405/vendor.qti.hardware.display.composer-service: 1.8% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 325 minor
      3.5% 9952/hybridswapd:0: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
      3.5% 183/kswapd0:0: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
      2.6% 649/logd: 0.4% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 3407 minor 34 major
      2.6% 9513/kworker/u24:0-devfreq_wq: 0% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 180 minor
    21% TOTAL: 9.5% user + 9.8% kernel + 0.2% iowait + 1.7% irq + 0.4% softirq
    CPU usage from 189ms to 1606ms later (2024-01-25 15:48:55.280 to 2024-01-25 15:48:56.698) with 99% awake:
      169% 1969/system_server: 67% user + 101% kernel / faults: 7529 minor 341 major
    71% 12305/AnrAuxiliaryTas: 21% user + 50% kernel
    56% 2064/Signal Catcher: 34% user + 22% kernel
    7% 7096/binder:1969_1F: 2.6% user + 4.4% kernel
    5.3% 2067/HeapTaskDaemon: 4.4% user + 0.8% kernel
    4.4% 7101/binder:1969_20: 2.6% user + 1.7% kernel
    1.7% 7094/binder:1969_1D: 0.8% user + 0.8% kernel
    1.7% 12303/AnrConsumer: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
    0.8% 2074/binder:1969_2: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 2842/Thread-5: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 3211/binder:1969_4: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 3408/android.imms: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 3989/LockSettingsSer: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 3993/tworkPolicy.uid: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 3994/WifiHandlerThre: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4009/ranker: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4011/NotificationSer: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4052/SliceManagerSer: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4058/ackgroundThread: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4084/init_criticallo: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4089/OplusWifiCPUThr: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4114/OplusNetworkSta: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4205/athena_killer: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4224/oSenseResHandle: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 4274/memFeatureT: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4621/HansStateMachin: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 4636/CpuLimitManager: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 6546/OwmIcmpMonitor: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
      77% 183/kswapd0:0: 0% user + 77% kernel
      113% 6113/com.google.android.providers.media.module: 38% user + 75% kernel / faults: 449 minor 31 major
    13% 13445/Thread-8: 6.8% user + 6.8% kernel
    12% 18569/Thread-13: 5.4% user + 6.8% kernel
    10% 6667/Thread-3: 2.7% user + 8.2% kernel
    10% 7042/Thread-12: 5.4% user + 5.4% kernel
    10% 20490/Thread-19: 2.7% user + 8.2% kernel
    10% 32141/Thread-9: 2.7% user + 8.2% kernel
    9.5% 4497/Thread-20: 4.1% user + 5.4% kernel
    9.5% 6670/Thread-4: 1.3% user + 8.2% kernel
    9.5% 9183/Thread-5: 4.1% user + 5.4% kernel
    9.5% 13140/Thread-7: 2.7% user + 6.8% kernel
    8.2% 20771/binder:6113_10: 1.3% user + 6.8% kernel
      102% 9948/in.games.balajimarket: 95% user + 6.3% kernel / faults: 1953 minor

I am loading 100 data into the recycler view at once and then the application crashes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your main thread is blocked for too long which is why it throws the ANR, consider doing the operation on a background thread or using asynchronous mechanisms like Coroutines or RxJava for loading your data.
